# Header Requirements to Put MathJax in d3-tips

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mathjax

I have been hacking away at javascript library d3.js with some help from more seasoned characters at school. I am sort of copy and pasting the bl.ocks.org examples together to create a visualization for my network growth model.  I am using d3-tips to have different node characteristics shown upon visualization.

Including this in the header allows me to use the standard MathJax formatting in the html body, but it doesn't work with d3-tips:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
    processEscapes: true
  }
});
</script>
```

I have been googling around and looking at the examples of one blogger in particular, but his examples are way too cryptic for my limited background.  Here are said examples from the blogger:

[Resource 1](http://www.nowherenearithaca.com/2014/01/using-mathjax-in-jquery-tooltip-one-way.html)

[Resource 2](http://www.nowherenearithaca.com/2013/12/equationlognormalhover-border1px-solid.html)

THANK YOU!

Comment: As a general comment, I would avoid d3.tip.js. It's not as customizable as you might like and it's very easy to make a tooltip.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple things:

1.) When you add MathJax content on the fly, it needs to be re-queued to [process](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html) it.

2.) The `d3.tip.js` seems to be eating the `\` escape character used in `LaTeX` so you'll need to double escape it.

Putting this together:

```
var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    setTimeout(function(){MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);}, 10);
    return "$ax^2 + bx + " + d.frequency + " = 0$" + "<br/>" + "\\(x_1 = 132\\)";
})
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FZSsl1vZfu9kOipGTmjH?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you, Mark.  The setTimeout was the key.  I am still feeling out javascript, so the example is really helpful to read!